# n-body Simulation expected performance barnes hut

Tags: java, algorithm, simulation, physics

I made a 2D n-body simulation using brute force at first, but then following http://arborjs.org/docs/barnes-hut this I've implemented a Barnes-Hut approximation algorithm. However this didn't give me the effect I was looking for.

Ex:

Barnes-Hut -> 2000 Bodies; frametime avg. 32 ms and 5000; 164 ms

Brute force -> 2000 Bodies; frametime avg. 31 ms and 5000; 195 ms

These values are with rendering turned off.

Am I correct to assume that I haven't correctly implemented the algorithm and am thus not getting a substantial increase in performance?

Theta is currently set to s/d < 0.5. Changing this value to e.g. 1 does increase performance, but it's quite obvious why this isn't preferred.

Single threaded

My code along general lines:

```
while(!close)
    {
        long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long frameTime = newTime-currentTime;
        System.out.println(frameTime);
        currentTime = newTime;

        update the bodies
    }
```

Within the function that updates the bodies:

```
first insert all bodies into the quadtree with all its subnodes
for all bodies
    {
        compute the physics using Barnes-Hut which yields a net force per planet (doPhysics(body))
        calculate instantaneous acceleration from net force
        update the instantaneous velocity
    }
```

The barneshut function:

```
doPhysics(body)
{
    if(node is external (contains 1 body) and that body is not itself)
    {
        calculate the force between those two bodies

    }else if(node is internal and s/d < 0.5)
    {
        create a pseudobody at the COM with the nodes total mass
        calculate the force between the body and pseudobody

    }else (if is it internal but s/d >= 0.5)
    {
        (this is where recursion comes in)
        doPhysics on same body but on the NorthEast subnode
        doPhysics on same body but on the NorthWest subnode
        doPhysics on same body but on the SouthEast subnode
        doPhysics on same body but on the SouthWest subnode
    }
}
```

Actually calculating the force:

```
calculateforce(body, otherbody)
{
    if(body is not at exactly the same position (avoid division by 0))
    {
        calculate force using newtons law of gravitation in vector form

        add the force to the bodies' net force in this frame
    }
}
```

Comment: without showing the code we can't really tell if it is correctly implemented

Comment: Yes, but also I was asking about the performance change. Maybe someone has experience and can tell me how much better a simulation is expected to run compared to brute force?

Comment: It is perfectly possible that the bottleneck is not the simulation, but rendering. Without more details on what you are doing, there is no way to comment on your algorithm's implementation.

Comment: I added my code as you requested.

Comment: @PeterLikesCode newer used nor heard of this algorithm before but from quick look at it the speedup depends on the dataset. If you do not have majority of the bodies grouped then the code could be actually slower than brute force due to added overhead. So the worse case scenario I can see is having uniformly distributed bodies ... as we do not know your bodies position (a screenshot would be nice) we can only guess you are either have small trade off or doing somethng ineffectivelly or even do the clustering too often

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still incomplete (read on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)s ), and in-depth debugging of incomplete code is not the purpose of the site. However, this is how I would approach the next steps of figuring what, if anything, is wrong:

- time *only* the function that you are worried about (let us call it barnes_hutt_update()); and not the whole update loop. Compare that to the equivalent, non-B-H code, and not to the whole update loop without B-H. This would result in a much more meaningful comparison.
- you seem to have hard-coded s/d 0.5 into your algorithm. Leaving it as an argument, you should be able to notice speedups when it is set higher; and very similar performance to a naive, non-B-H implementation if set to 0. Speedup in B-H comes from evaluating less nodes (because far-away nodes are lumped together); do you know how many nodes you are managing to skip? *No skipped nodes, no speedup.* On the other hand, skipping nodes introduces small errors in the calculation - have you quantified those?
- *have a look at other implementations of B-H online*. D3's [force layout](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/src/manyBody.js) uses it internally, and is quite readable. There are multiple existing quadtree implementations. If you have built your own, they may be sub-optimal (or even buggy). Unless you are trying to learn-by-doing, it is always better to use a tested library instead of rolling your own.
- slowdown may be due to the use of quadtrees, rather than from force addition itself. It would be useful to know how long building and updating the quadtree is taking, as compared to the B-H force aproximation itself -- because quadtrees are, in this case, pure overhead. B-H needs quadtrees, but the naive, non-B-H implementation does not. For small amounts of nodes, naive will be faster (but will get slower very fast as you add more and more). *How does the performance scale as you add more and more bodies*?
- are you creating and discarding large amounts of objects? You can make your algorithm avoid the associated overhead (yes, *lots of news + garbage collection can result in significant slowdowns*) by using a [memory pool](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management#object-pooling).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a much cleaner explanation of the algorithm https://jheer.github.io/barnes-hut/

It also has a benchmark chart which shows that for that particular implementation, with theta=0.5, the cutoff for where BH becomes more efficient is 6k bodies, which makes sense, since constructing the quadtree has an overhead that the naive solution does not have.

The better question here should be: how does the performance of the two solutions scale relative to the number of bodies and the parameter theta?